# Preserve lines in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: utf-8, nlp, stanford-nlp, tokenize, chinese-locale

From https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.html , the Stanford tokenizer has the option `-preserveLines` to preserve the line breaks determined by the `\n` in a text file.

But in CoreNLP, there is the `ssplit` that splits the sentences and breaks the lines up.

So given the text file:

```
生告激効雑題鹿際写徹輝万。最協領野京部習頂経日交日考当備。
foo foo bar bar.
```

The desired output to just tokenize the file should be:

```
生 告 激効 雑題 鹿際 写 徹輝万 。 最協領 野京部 習頂経 日 交日 考 当備 。
foo foo bar bar .
```

Using the Chinese CoreNLP models:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
cp stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar .
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-english-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
echo -e "生告激効雑題鹿際写徹輝万。最協領野京部習頂経日交日考当備。\nfoo foo bar bar." > input.txt

java -mx10g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props stanford-tools/StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.tokenize.properties -file input.txt -outputFormat text
```

And the `stanford-chinese.properties` file should look like this:

```
annotators = segment, ssplit
customAnnotatorClass.segment = edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ChineseSegmenterAnnotator
segment.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/ctb.gz
segment.sighanCorporaDict = edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese
segment.serDictionary = edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict-chris6.ser.gz
segment.sighanPostProcessing = true
ssplit.boundaryTokenRegex = [.]|[!?]+|[。]|[！？]+
```

(Note: the Stanford CoreNLP for chinese don't write to file if the `ssplit` isn't used, see https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/409)

And the output produces 3 lines instead of 2:

```
生 告 激効 雑題 鹿際 写 徹輝万 。 
最協領 野京部 習頂経 日 交日 考 当備 。
foo foo bar bar .
```

Using `-preserveLines` option with the following command yields the same result:

```
java -mx10g -cp "stanford-tools/*"  edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props stanford-tools/StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.tokenize.properties -preserveLines -file input.txt
```

---

There is no explicit option int he Stanford segmenter to preseve the lines from https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml#Questions

I understand that I can simply use the Stanford segmenter without the fuller NLP suite to segment using:

```
wget https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-segmenter-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-segmenter-2016-10-31.zip
cd stanford-segmenter-2016-10-13
./segment.sh ctb input.txt utf-8 0
```

[out]:

```
生 告 激効 雑題 鹿際 写 徹輝万 。 最協領 野京部 習頂経 日 交日 考 当備 。
```

foo foo bar bar .

But the question still remains on Stanford CoreNLP, i.e. **can Stanford CoreNLP with the Chinese model preserve linebreaks?**

Answer (score 2):

Our system is set up to handle Chinese newswire documents where the newline is similar to empty string.  For instance, in English a token would not be broken by a newline, but in a Chinese newswire document tokens might be broken up by a newline.

That being said, there have been a fair amount of requests to add a one sentence per line option for Chinese.  I am going to see if I can make a few changes to the code and implement this for Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0.

Comment: I'll be glad to contribute if it's possible to some sort of preserve newline feature in all languages =)